# regarding memory allocated using malloc()

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following code

```
int *i;

i=(int *)malloc(1);

*i=5;

printf("%d",*i);
```

Output: `5`

In the above code, I requested `malloc()` to allocate `1` byte of memory using `malloc(1)` but of integer type.
The size of `int` is `4` bytes, but in the above code `i` is allocated just `1` byte.
So how it is able to store `5` in it?

### EDIT

After reading the marked question, I want to know that is there any difference between

`(int *)malloc(1)` and `(int *)malloc(4)` other than overwriting in the first case

Comment: @KerrekSB: Unable to establish the relation...

Comment: Basketball has a rule saying you can't hold the ball. This doesn't mean you're physically prevented from doing so. The fact that you were able to hold the ball and got away with it doesn't mean the rule doesn't exist, just that the consequences of violating it are not always clear. In this case, you violated a rule whose consequence is undefined behavior; having the code appear to "work" is actually the worst thing that can happen (since it makes it harder to detect the error).